# "integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type" when finding largest prime factor

Tags: c++, prime-factoring

I am working on solving Euler project 3:

```
Description: The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
             What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
```

This is my code to generate the answer.  However I need an integer type to hold `600851475143`.  When I compile this on GCC on a Mac I get:

```
integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type".
```

I expect long long could easily hold this number.  I also tried making it unsigned. Why doesn't my code hold that small number and what can I do to make it work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

static bool IsPrimeFactor(int numToTest,int testNum,vector<int> factors)
{
    if(numToTest%testNum==0) // is it a factor?
    {
        // see if it is a prime factor
        for(unsigned int i=0; i < factors.size(); i++)
        {
            if(testNum%factors[i]==0)  // see if this factor
            {                          //is divisble by one we have already

                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long long numToTest=600851475143;
    unsigned int testNum=2;  // 0 and 1 are assumed
    vector<int> factors;   

    while(testNum<numToTest)   // don't go higher than the max num
    {
        if(IsPrimeFactor(numToTest,testNum,factors)) // is it a factor?
        {
            factors.push_back(testNum); // got through prime factors 
        }                                   // and none divided it

        testNum++;
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0; i < factors.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "factor " <<factors[i] << endl;
    }

    cout<<"Highest factor: " << factors[factors.size()-1]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have some serious conceptual problems in your code there - i don't want to spoil your fun doing project euler, but you might want to read up a bit on how to do prime factorization ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c) question. You have to specify your literal like this:

```
600851475143LL
```

Comment: As of C++11, an unsuffixed decimal integer constant is of type `int`, `long int`, or `long long int`, depending on its type. In C++03, it was `int` or `long int` -- because the type `long long int` didn't exist yet. A conforming compiler that supports `long long int` *should* accept an unsuffixed literal like that, but an older compiler that supports `long long int` as an extension might not. Invoking the compiler with `-std=c++11` or equivalent (if your compiler supports it) should work. On the other hand, adding the `LL` suffix is harmless and arguably clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As @Space_C0wb0y said, you need to specify a suffix for the literal.

Also, you're going to have a problem with your `IsPrimeFactor` function - the parameters are ints, but as you've already discovered, an int or even a long is not big enough to store the number you'll be passing in repeatedly...

Comment: Thanks. I know that function will need some refactoring.