# Setting up 64 bit variables in C++

Tags: c++, 64-bit

I'm wondering how to set a 64-bit variable in C++ for my testbench. When I use the `variable_name.io_int_write(0,value0)` and `variable_name.io_int_write(1,value1)` (for the lower & upper bits) I can see the variables are set but in the reverse manner.

Ex: When I want it to be 000...002, I see 200...000

Is there an alternate command that would help? Thanks

Edit: I have a function `void set_function (set_ * dut)`

and inside this function, I need to set a 64-bit variable `dut->variable_name`

Thanks for your answers, how would I go about fixing the Endianness in this case

Comment: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Endianness

Comment: I believe this is related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you are trying to do? For simply setting a 64bit variable, you could declare something as int64_t or uint64_t (both types declared in <cstdint> or <stdint.h>), or even long long. They can be set and handled without any special functions. And yes, what you see there is an endianness problem.

Comment: I might be wrong, but to me this seems more likely an endianess issue. Could you give us more context? Which is the type of variable_name? hw running the code? what do you mean exactly by "I see..."?

Comment: Thanks all! I'm using this C++ testbench for my verilog code, and when I said "I see" it was from the wave I got on ModelSim. I have 2 32-bit variables, which make up the 64-bit variable. I want to change the values to see the change in outputs

Comment: are you aware of big and little endianess of a machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set a 64bit integer variable to a constant value, you can simply say something like:

```
long long var64bit = 1L;
```

The *L* at the end of *1L* says that it is a 64bit constant value of *1*.

If you are comfortable with hexadecimal and want a 64bit bit-field constant, then the usual way of setting a 64bit variable would look something like this:

```
unsigned long long bitfield64bit = 0xDEADBEEFDEADBEEFL;
```

Again, note the trailing *L*.

If you have two 32bit values that you want to pack into a 64bit value, then you can do this using shift and logical-OR operations as:

```
long long var64bit = (long long)(((unsigned long long)high_bits << 32) | (unsigned long long)low_bits);
```

where *high_bits* is the 32bit variable holding the high bits and *low_bits* is the 32bit variable containing the low bits.  I do the bit-wise operations on unsigned values because of possibly excess paranoia regarding the sign bit and conversion between 32bit and 64bit integers.

The opposite operations, dividing a 64bit variable into high and low bits can be done as follows:

```
int high_bits = (int)(var64bit & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
int low_bits = (int)((var64bit >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFFL);
```

Comment: The `L` suffix just means `long`. `long long` and `unsigned long long` are not (yet) C++ types,

Comment: Although it is not part of the official standard, most compilers support an `LL` suffix for long long constants. Check your compiler documentation OP. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c