# integer constant is too large for "long" type

Tags: c++, dev-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [long long in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c)

Writing a simple program for a project Euler problem. Refuses to compile because *"integer constant is too large for "long" type"*, even though it should be well within the size limits of an **unsigned long long**. Using the dev-c++ compiler.

code in question:

```
#include <iostream>

bool isprime (unsigned long long i)
{
    if(i==1||i==0) return false;
    if(i==2) return true;
    for(unsigned long long k=2;k!=i-1;k++)
    {      
        if(i%k==0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    for(unsigned long long i=600851475143;i>=0;i--) //problematic line
    {
        if(isprime(i))
        {
            std::cout<<i;
            std::cin.get();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c

Comment: Looks like http://projecteuler.net/problem=3 :-) Found this answer while trying to solve the same :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try an "ULL" suffix: `600851475143ULL`

Answer (score 4):

Your literal as typed has type `int` which isn't big enough to hold the value. Try `600851475143ULL` as a first fix.

Note even with that, your `for` loop will never terminate since an unsigned can never be less than 0. Instead, use a `long long` and `600851475143LL`.

Answer (score 0):

Must be a limitation of dev-c++ support for **long long** datatype. It compiles fine on MS VC++ 2010.

Comment: That would be a bug in MS VC++ 2010 then, unless its native `int` type is 64 bits. The literal as typed is an `int`.

Comment: I don't want to get into a long discussion on this, but I'd always understood that a good compiler should choose the most appropriate datatype for internal representation of literals that don't explicitly specify it. In this case the value is capable of being stored in a **long long**, but it seems the copmpiler chooses to use just **long** before even looking at either the actual value, or the assignment destination. I'm no great fan of MS in general, but their way does seem 'better' to me in this case.

Comment: ps - I know the formal definition for c++ says numeric literals are stored in whatever the compiler uses as its native **int** type. But I wouldn't call the MS approach a *bug* - it's more of a *non-standard extension* to me.