# Compiling with arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc: int64_t is 32 bit long

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I'm cross compiling for imx28 cpu with arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi:

```
[vladimir@vladimir src]$ arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi
Configured with: /work/arm-toolchains/tmp/src/gcc-4.4.4/configure --build=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/work/arm_fsl_gcc_4.4.4_multilib --with-sysroot=/work/arm_fsl_gcc_4.4.4_multilib/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/multi-libs --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-pkgversion=4.4.4_09.06.2010 --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --with-gmp=/work/arm-toolchains/tmp/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-mpfr=/work/arm-toolchains/tmp/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-ppl=/work/arm-toolchains/tmp/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-cloog=/work/arm-toolchains/tmp/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --with-local-prefix=/work/arm_fsl_gcc_4.4.4_multilib/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/multi-libs --disable-nls --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-lto
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.4 (4.4.4_09.06.2010)
```

The following code line:

```
info->mask = 0xffffffffffffffff;
```

gives me following error:

```
warning: integer constant is too large for 'long' type
```

I tried close to everything, made sure int64_t is defined to long long int, even tried to typedef it manually, still, it gives me the error.

I also tried different -mcpu options.

Is there even a way to use int64_t on imx28, or should I just give up?

Comment: what does sizeof() show (dont need to execute just compile a three line test program and disassemble), also what if you try -1 instead of that number and or force that number to be signed, maybe the compiler thinks it is unsigned and the error is correct.  Try 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL

Comment: is  your host 32bit, it may be picking up the wrong stdint.h

Comment: ahh it says long type yes long is 32 bits you need long long.  so you probably have an stdint.h problem what if you declare it long long what happens?

Comment: `made sure int64_t is defined to long long int,` - but what type is `info->mask`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, info->mask is int64_t

Comment: @old_timer if I declare it long long it still shows me exactly same error

Comment: then you have a problem if you declare it long long and it interprets that as a long.  are you looking at the right line of code?

Comment: @old_timer I definitely am looking at the right line, also I nailed it down to a simple 2-liner, which also gives me same error no matter if I use stdint.h or typedef uint64_t manually as unsigned long long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment.

Try 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFLL  or -1

Comment: In the end of the day, I found a (essentially) duplicate question here: [integer constant is too large for “long” type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541560/integer-constant-is-too-large-for-long-type)
@old_timer is totally right, some targets need LL or ULL in the end of the constants, or they count them as just L/UL.