# Upper bound of the calculation ability of computer in c

Tags: c, windows, compiler-construction, operating-system

I have a question about the number of bytes that a computer normally use to do calculation. First of all, i want you to see the source code below.

**source code**

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(444444444));
printf("%d\n", 444444444);

printf("%d\n", sizeof(4444444444));
printf("%llu\n", 4444444444);
```

**output**

```
4
444444444
8
4444444444
```

As you can see, the computer never loses the value. If it were to be too big to fit in an int, The computer itself would automatically extend it's type. I think the reason why the computer never loses the value is because it operates originally on big type already at least bigger than the 8-bit container.

Would you guys let me know the overall mechanism? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: When you use a numeric literal, the compiler automatically selects the appropriate data type into which that value will fit. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @CodyGray You mean to tell me that even if i didn't type the suffix right after a number, The compiler would automatically append appropriate suffix? Sorry for irritating you. But I just want to know exactly what is happening down there. Is it specifically stated in c99?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This has nothing to do with the "calculation ability of [the] computer".**

Your example is all about the size of the integer literal you're dealing with, at the compilation stage. An `int` on *most* platforms is four bytes (32 bits).  This has a maximum value of 0x7FFF_FFFF or 2147483647.  An `unsigned int` has a maximum of 0xFFFF_FFFF or 4294967295.

The compiler will typically default to `int` for most integer literals, (as with the 4 byte example).  Your next value is 0x1_08e8_d71c which is too big for an `int`, so the literal is promoted to an 8-byte literal, `long long`.

This is probably a warning on most compilers.

GCC, (in 32-bit mode, `-m32`) gives the following warning, because `long` is only 4 bytes:

> warning: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type

Output

> `sizeof(int)=4, sizeof(long)=4, sizeof(long long)=8`

In 64-bit mode however, (`-m64`) GCC is cool with it, because `long` is 8-bytes.

> `sizeof(int)=4, sizeof(long)=8, sizeof(long long)=8`

To remedy this, you should use the `LL` suffix:

```
long long val = 4444444444LL;
```

- [long long in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is that specified in the c99 standard?

Comment: I'm sure it is, I'm just not sure off the top of my head. I'm sure one of those crazy standards guys will come around and trump me :-)

Comment: What is the limit of the promotion? Is that possible for computer to promote a number up to 16byte, 32byte, 64byte? Although i know that's ridiculous because the proper types for 16byte or something like that is not currently found. I just want to know the possibility.

Comment: @bis0317 I don't believe any C compilers support native arithmetic for values larger than 8 bytes. If you want to use larger integers, you'll have to use a "big number" library, like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).