# How to store a integer value equal to 10^18 in c programs or c++?

Tags: c++, c

How can I store a large integer value in a variable of C ?
If i am declaring a with `int a;` it won't work.
I have used this with `long long int`.It is not working.

```
if( a>=0 && a <= (1000000000000000000))
```

What to declare variable a so that it will not so any error.It should be integer.

```
Compiler error
integer constant is too large for long type.
```

Comment: What research did you perform on this topic?

Comment: Note that you have to append the "LL" suffix for a long long integer literal: `1000000000000000000LL`.

Comment: @MartinR: That's not true (2.14.2/2).

Comment: @Martin You may, but you don't have to.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I just read the comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c#comment10877837_1458934 that you linked to in your comment below. That was new to me! Does that apply only to C++ or to C as well?

Comment: Well I guess if one is really desperate... You could try parsing it as a string...

Comment: @Martin - I have used this with LL, however it is not working as i want. It is accepting example, -12 also, if (a>=0 should not allow this.

Comment: @user3599293: You should read the chapter in your book about _signedness_.

Comment: `struct { int mantissa, exp; } value { 10, 18 }; // pronto!`

Answer (score 1):

Try a [`unsigned long long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx#bkmkRemarks), assuming the value is positive, it can hold up to

```
18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

(VS 13)
However, you must use the `ULL` syntax.

Comment: You need to inform the OP that to do this he requires the `ULL` suffix (otherwise the value will be a [signed] `long long` _if_ his `long long` is long enough). Otherwise he's just going to change the type of `a` and nothing will happen. You also need to inform him that C++ didn't not even define `long long` until C++11, which he may not be using.

Comment: @user3599293: To read a long long you have to use `scanf("%lld",&a)` .

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at this `if` statement you wrote:

```
if( a>=0 && a <= (1000000000000000000))
```

`1000000000000000000` is too big for an integral literal so you will need a bigger literal type. You should declare `a` as an `int64_t` and do the comparion like that:

```
if( a>=INT64_C(0) && a <= INT64_C(1000000000000000000))
```

Note that this will only work in a `C99` or `C++11` compiler when you `#include <cstdint>` or `#include <stdint.h>`

Edit: in current draft of the standard you can find this sentence (2.14.2/2):

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list
>   in Table 6 in which its value can be represented.

It means that compiler should use the required literal type automatically to make your literal fit. Btw I didn't see that kind of compiler.

Comment: _Yet again_, no, the literal will have the type it needs to fit the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `long long` to store this integer. A `long long` is guranteed to hold at least 64 bits.

The problem with this code: `if( a>=0 && a <= (1000000000000000000))` is that you need to give the literal (`1000000000000000000`) the suffix `LL` if you want it to be of type `long long` or `ULL` for `unsigned long long`.

Comment: `you need to give the literal (1000000000000000000) the suffix LL if you want it to be of type long long` Once again, no, that is not true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed the new C++ standards mandate that the integral literal be of type `long long` if `int` and `long` is not enough to represent it. However, you can never trust the C++ compiler (especially those from Microsoft) for its standard compliance. It's better to be explicit.

Comment: @C.R. I would agree with that. Still, one should not make patently false claims.