# C and number suffixes

Tags: c

I've got a question about using suffix for numbers in C.

Example:

```
long long c;
```

The variable c is of long long type. To initiate its value, I do (usually)

```
c = 12;
```

When done like that, the compiler recognizes c as a long long type.

Then, if I do

```
printf("%d",sizeof(c));
```

the result is 8 - which of course is 64 bit. So the compiler remembers that c is of long long type.

But I've seen some examples where I need to force the type to be long long, by doing

```
c = 12LL
```

Why is that?

Comment: Maybe look at this..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c

Comment: Note: `printf("%d",sizeof(c));` is not portable.  Better to use `printf("%zu", sizeof(c));`.

Comment: Btw, sizeof is an operator (not a function), yet i rarely see it used without the parentheses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're declaring the variable `c` as a `long long`, so it's a `long long int`. The type of the variable is not dependent on its value; rather, the range of possible values for `c` is dependent on the type of `c`.

On the other hand: For an integer constant/literal, the type is determined by its value and suffix (if any). 12 has no prefix, so it's a decimal constant. And it has no suffix, meaning it has a type of `int`, since 12 is guaranteed to be in the long range of it. `12LL` has no prefix, so it's also a decimal constant. It has a suffix of `LL`, meaning it has a type of `long long int`. It's safe to assign 12 to the variable `c`, because an int can safely be converted to a `long long int`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah. I would like to say "ah, of course!", but I'll settle for "Ah" :-)

Comment: "12 has no prefix, so it's a decimal constant." is incomplete.  `0` is an unsigned octal constant. `012345` is also an unsigned octal constant.  On a 32-bit machine `4000000000` is an unsigned decimal.  This answer's discussion on suffixes is good, but constants with/without prefixes need calcification.

Answer (score 2):

```
long long c;
c = 12;
```

`c` is of type `long long` but `12` is of type `int`. When `12` is assigned to `long long` object `c` it is first converted to `long long` and then assigned to `c`.

```
c = 12LL;
```

does exactly the same assignment, only there is no need to implicitly convert it first. Both assignments are equivalent and no sane compiler will make a difference.

Note that some coding guides, from example MISRA (for automotive embedded code) requires constants assigned to unsigned types to be suffixed with `U`:

Example, in C both assignments (here `unsigned int x;`) are equivalent:

```
 x = 0;   /* non-MISRA compliant */
 x = 0U;
```

but MISRA requires the second form (MISRA-C:2004, rule 10.6).