# How to dynamically allocate big memory , like 10 G ,using new operator in c++ on 64-linux?

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I need to dynamically allocate a larger float array for a special application using C++ new operator, like 10G. The code running on 64-ubuntu-14.04 Linux OS with 64G memory.
When I set the request of memory as about 7G ,`1879048192x4/(1024x1024x1024)=7G` (float has 4 bytes), like this :

```
float * data; 
data = new float[1879048192];
```

The program works well, but when I try to increase the request to 10G , I got a  `what():  std::bad_alloc`. I also try to use `malloc()` to take place of new operator:

```
data =(float*)malloc(1879048192*sizeof(float));
```

But obtain the same result.  My `ulimit -a` is this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 514689
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 514689
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Someone may say there might be no 10G continual memory for the allocation, but I close all other progresses and the total memory is 64G. I want to know whether I can obtain this larger array or not, and how. Does the Linux limit the max number for this dynamically allocation? Where and how?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77549/discussion-on-question-by-changingivan-how-to-dynamically-allocate-big-memory).

Comment: Oh no, [not again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30173133/linux-cannot-allocate-more-than-32-gb-64-gb-of-memory-in-a-single-process-due-t/30174109#30174109).

Comment: What is the type of constant 1879048192 and 1879048192*sizeof(float)? How you will write 10G constant? Try to use `long long` constants with LL suffix (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1458934): 1879048192LL; or compute size without large constants in long long typed variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem when I try it.  Both `new` and `malloc` worked. My system runs Ubuntu 15.04 and has 16G of ram.

However, if I try to use the memory, I found I needed to be very careful about the types of vars used to index into the data array.

For instance, the program below can do undesirable things with only `long int`and `float`, because a `long int` has a max value of `2^31` and the array length for 10Gi will be longer than `2^31`.  Also, floats only add `1.0` at a time to `16777216.0`. With doubles, it is ok to use long int indexes here because the array is shorter.

use10G.c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  long long int ten = 10;
  long long int megi = 1024*1024;
  long long int gigi = 1024*megi;
  long long int asize = (ten*gigi)/((long int) sizeof(double));
  double * data = new double[asize];
  long long int i=2;
  printf("A double is %zd bytes\n", (size_t) sizeof(double));
  printf("Array size is %lli \n", asize);
  data[0]=0.0;
  data[1]=1.0;
  while (i<asize) {
    data[i]=data[i-1]+1.0;
    ++i;
  }
  printf("%lf\n", (double) data[asize-1]);
  printf("success\n");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

A double is 8 bytes
Array size is 1342177280 
1342177279.000000
success
```

Comment: you are right ! It seems that I make a stupid mistake about the index, thanks a lot ! mo mo da !