# What is the size of long long integer in a 32-bit computer?

Tags: c

What is the size of long long integer in a 32-bit computer?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     unsigned long long var = 0LL;
     printf("%d",sizeof(var));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof (long long));`

Comment: See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c)

Comment: According to your program, the size is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, right?

Comment: Even an 8 bits machine is able to emulate 64 bits long long variable. It is compiler dependent. I think C99 compliant compiler defines long long as 64 bits even in 32 bits machine.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the size of long long integer in a 32-bit computer?

The type of computer is irrelevant.  The value of the `long long` variable/object is irrelevant. The issues are the compiler and the C spec.

C requires `long long` to represent a *minimum* range or `[-9223372036854775807 ... 9223372036854775807]`, that takes at *least* 64-bits  (See C11dr §5.2.4.2.1 1).

A 32-bit computer will *likely* use  a 64-bit implementation.  A  future compiler may use 128-bit `long long`.

When printing, use a matching print specifier `"%zu"` for the return type of `sizeof`, which is `size_t`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("size: %zu\n", sizeof(long long));
  printf("bit size: %zu\n", sizeof(long long) * CHAR_BIT);
}
```

---

`printf(sizeof(var));` is invalid code as the first parameter to `printf()` needs to be a string, not an integer.  Insure your compiler warnings are fully enabled.

Comment: Can you please add references?

Comment: @Rotem reference added.