# C++ literal integer type

Tags: c++, int, long-integer, integer-overflow

Do literal expressions have types too ?

```
long long int a = 2147483647+1 ;
long long int b = 2147483648+1 ; 
std::cout << a << ',' << b ; // -2147483648,2147483649
```

Comment: because yo do the `a+1` first and then cast it to long long.

Comment: check this, you will have all your doubts cleared:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819189/what-range-of-values-can-integer-types-store-in-c

Comment: I don't see how a question about long long is relevant to the question "Do literal expressions have types too ?".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [long long in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458923/long-long-in-c-c)

Comment: The answer is "yes", and 2147483647 will either be of type int or (at most) long.  I know of no current implementation where adding one to it won't overflow.

Comment: A [linked question on the same matter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61624859/6372809) also has [answers with longer discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61652133/6372809) on the matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, literal numbers have types. The type of an unsuffixed decimal integer literal is the first of `int`, `long`, `long long` in which the integer can be represented. The type of binary, hex and octal literals is selected similarly but with unsigned types in the list as well.

You can force the use of unsigned types by using a `U` suffix. If you use a single `L` in the suffix then the type will be at least `long` but it might be `long long` if it cannot be represented as a `long`. If you use `LL`, then the type must be `long long` (unless the implementation has extended types wider than `long long`).

The consequence is that if `int` is a 32-bit type and `long` is 64 bits, then `2147483647` has type `int` while `2147483648` has type `long`. That means that `2147483647+1` will overflow (which is undefined behaviour), while `2147483648+1` is simply `2147483649L`.

This is defined by §2.3.12 (`[lex.icon]`) paragraph 2 of the C++ standard, and the above description is a summary of Table 7 from that section.

It's important to remember that the type of the destination of the assignment does not influence in any way the value of the expression on the right-hand side of the assignment. If you want to force a computation to have a `long long` result you need to force some argument of the computation to be `long long`; just assigning to a `long long` variable isn't enough:

```
long long a = 2147483647 + 1LL;
std::cout << a << '\n';
```

produces

```
2147483648
```

([live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fd3837644a3eef7))

Comment: Is it an obligation to use the smallest integer type in which it can be represented? Can you provide a citation?

Comment: @m7913d: Yes, the standard says exactly "first of the corresponding list". I added the citation. (It's not the smallest integer type in which it can be represented; it will not be `char` or `short`, ever.)

Comment: @rici: It is worth noting that a literal char, such as `'a'` will be of type `char` (unlike C, where it will be of type `int`).

Comment: @rodrigo, yes and a literal with a decimal point will be of type `double` :) Character literals are in a different section of the standard, with a large set of different types (for example, `u'a'` has type `char16_t`). I don't think those complications really add anything to this question, but you are free to disagree.

Comment: In addition to all the above, note that the Microsoft compilers use 32-bit int and 32-bit long, so 2147483648 has type `long long`, and 2147483647L + 1 will also overflow.

Comment: `LL` suffix for a literal that does not fit in `long long`, may get a larger extended signed integer type

Comment: @M.M: True. Edited. (Do you know of an applicable implementation, by the way?)

Comment: I don't know of any. gcc does have a 128-bit extended type but declines to take up the latitude permitted by the standard to allow literals that would fit in it

Comment: @M.M: yep. That's pretty common, I believe. For example, ICC has wide types for use in intrinsics, but they are not extended integer types.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a = INT_MAX ;
long long int b = a + 1 ; // adds 1 to a and convert it then to long long ing
long long int c = a; ++c; // convert a to long long int and increment the result with 1
cout << a << std::endl; // 2147483647
cout << b << std::endl; // -2147483648
cout << c << std::endl; // 2147483648
cout << 2147483647 + 1 << std::endl; // -2147483648 (by default integer literal is assumed to be int)
cout << 2147483647LL + 1 << std::endl; // 2147483648 (force the the integer literal to be interpreted as a long long int)
```

You can find more information about integer literals [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal).

Comment: 2147483647 may be of type `int`, but it might also be of type long.  Furthermore, 2147483647 + 1 is likely to be integer overflow, which isn't -2147483648, but undefined behaviour.  Finally 2147483647L + 1 can *also* overflow (and will with Microsoft compilers).

Comment: @MartinBonner I changed my answer to use long long, which is also 64bit on Windows. Note that although it is undefined behaviour according to the c++ standard, it is almost always implemented as a 2 complement overflow and this was the behavior the OP noticed.

Comment: @MartinBonner According to rici's answer, it should be an int (if you assume int is 32bit)

Comment: @m7913d: I think Martin's point was that it is possible for `int` to be 16 bits while `long` must be at least 32 bits. With 16-bit `int` and 32-bit `long`, then the literal 2147483647 has type `long` (but adding one is still an overflow).

Comment: It is worth knowing that integer overflow often behaves as two-complement (for debugging and predicting how a buggy program got into the state it did, but it's also worth calling out it is undefined behaviour and that *anything* can happen.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33498 where GCC turns a perfectly ordinary loop counting from 0 to 63 into an infinite loop because of integer overflow

Comment: `a+1` causes undefined behaviour