# Is "auto" safe from the integer overflow in C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, integer-overflow, auto

If I write the code like this:

```
auto n = 2048 * 2048 * 5;
char* buf = new char[n];
```

So, Is `auto` deduction type safe from the integer overflow in C++17?

Comment: `2048 * 2048 * 5` is deduced to `int` no matter the overflow. The deduction only cares about types, not values.

Comment: I'm curious, what lead you to ask about C++17 specifically?

Comment: @Borgleader C++17 is latest version of C++.

Comment: `auto` doesn't magically fix overflows or change variable types. It just tells the compiler "please figure out the type here" instead of you having to write it yourself.

Comment: `auto` is a red herring. The expression on the right has to be valid on its own first.

Comment: @Mahendra Yes, but to my knowledge there arent any changes in that version of the standard that would affect this behavior. hence my question.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892227/c-literal-integer-type

Comment: There's... not even any overflow here.

Comment: @Barry 16-bit ints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`2048` and `5` in C++ have a type, and that type is `int`. Multiplying two `int`'s has a type and that type is `int`. There are values for which the result cannot fit in an `int`, and `auto` cannot prevent that.

What `auto` can prevent is accidentally narrowing the result, e.g.:

```
short x = 4 * 8192;
```